# Export AWS RDS Snapshot to GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I have a pipeline that exports automatic RDS backups to AWS S3. The database exported is Postgres from an Aurora Standard Cluster.

I also prepared a transfer job from the GCP side that copies these DB exports from S3 to Cloud Storage.

My question is, is it possible to use these backups from GCP cloud Storage and use them to spin up a Postgres database on GCP? If yes, what services should I use? Should I just create a CloudSQL and restore the DB from the files I have? Would it be possible with the same format that got exported from AWS or do I need to do some transformations on the Data? I think there's also the option of using Database Migration? AlloyDB? What's the best plan to follow for this use case.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I don't think it's possible to restore an RDS snapshot to GCP. It's going to have a bunch of RDS specific stuff in it and unless GCP explicitly built functionality to handle that, it's not going to work the same way as restoring to RDS.  If you can tolerate downtime, the easiest way would be to `pg_dump` from rds and pipe that into `psql` connecting to GCP.

Comment: What is your actual goal? Are you wanting backups, or are you wanting to transfer the database to GCP? These are very different requirements with different solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Exporting DB snapshot data to Amazon S3 - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html):

> When you export a DB snapshot, Amazon RDS extracts data from the snapshot and stores it in an Amazon S3 bucket. The data is stored in an Apache Parquet format that is compressed and consistent.

You would therefore need a process that can read the Parquet files into the database on GCP. You would also need to create the tables, indexes, etc. That's a lot of work.

Since you are using PostgreSQL, the easiest method would be to use `pg_dump` to extract the data. The export format is actual SQL commands that can be run in another PostgreSQL database. With the right options, the dump file will include the commands to recreate the original schemas and tables, plus the data. It can be loaded simply by sending the dump file to a `psql` command on the receiving database.